# Used for calculating String length whether its Greater that 16 and less than 13

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx expression to check the below:

1. Alphanumeric characters accepted
   (OR)
2. Length of the string is less than OR EQUAL TO 13 and more than 16 accepted as well

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: Can you show us some sample inputs?

Comment: Please add in comments what have you tried to do so far. This is not a freelance site which will provide you what you require. You would have to attempt to solve the question. If you're stuck we would help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

numeric and alphabet up to to 13 characters , or more than 16 for alphabet and numeric

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{0,13}|[A-Za-z0-9]{16,}$/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 3):

You can use alteration:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{0,13}|[A-Za-z0-9]{16,})$
```

Explanation of the regex:

`^` beginning of line

`|` alteration (OR operator)

`[A-Za-z0-9]` matches any symbol in the following ranges: A-Z, a-z, 0-9.

`{x,y}` matches x to y characters. i.e., `0,13` means from 0 to 13, `16,` means from 16 to infinity.

`$` end of line

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
^(.{0,13}|.{17,}|\w{14,16})$
```

This will match any string whose length is less than or equal to 13 characters or greater than 16 (any type of character).  And it will *also* match a string whose length is between 14 and 16 characters (inclusive) containing only alphanumeric characters.

## Regex101

Answer (score 1):

This regex accepts up to 13 and above 16 characters (case insensitive):

```
/^([a-z0-9]{0,13}|[a-z0-9]{16,})$/i
```